# Proof of a statement from Steele's "Probability theory and combinatorial optimization"

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry

I am reading "Probability theory and combinatorial optimization" by J.M. Steele and am hung up on a statement made in Section 2.2 of Chapter 2, "Easy size bounds", in which it is stated (paraphrasing for brevity) that for a set of $n$ points $\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ independent and uniformly distributed in $[0,1]^2$, there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $$\mathbf{E} \min\{ |X_i-X_j| : X_i,X_j  \in\{ X_1,\dots,X_n \} \}\geq c/\sqrt{n} $$.  The author says that it is due to "a computation that perfectly parallels the proof of Lemma 2.1.1".  Is there a direct reference, or an obvious proof, for this result somewhere?  I would think the lower bound would be $c/n$ because there are $n(n-1)/2$ total pairs that we're looking at.

I looked at Lemma 2.1.1 in this book, which basically puts an *upper* bound on the quantity $ \mathbf{E} \min_i \| x-X_i \| $ for an arbitrary point $x\in [0,1]^2$, and the details of how one might recover a proof of the above result are not clear to me.  The two seem quite different because the above result deals with $n*(n-1)/2$ total edges, whereas Lemma 2.1.1 deals only with $n$ edges between the point $x$ and the other points $X_i$.

Comment: I'd like to see an answer to this too. My heuristic agrees with yours. The probability that a particular $X_i$ does not lie within $r$ of another $X_j$ is essentially $(1-r^2)^n\approx e^{-r^2n}$. Assuming the distances to the nearest $X_j$ are independent for different $i$ and $i'$, the probability that *no* pair of $X_i$'s are within a distance $r$ is approximately $e^{-r^2n^2}$. If $r\approx 1/\sqrt n$, this is outrageously small.

Comment: My simulations give an average minimum distance of very close to 1/n (and nowhere near $1/\sqrt{n}$) for n in [20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280]. The minimum distances, averaged over ten thousand trials at each value of n, were [0.0515, 0.0245, 0.0120, 0.00599, 0.00296, 0.00147, 0.000738]. For comparison, 1/n is [0.05, 0.025, 0.0125, 0.00625, 0.003125, 0.0015625, 0.00078125] and $1/\sqrt{n}$ is [0.224, 0.1587, 0.112, 0.079, 0.056, 0.040, 0.028].

Answer (score 1):

The most natural way (to me) of thinking about this question is the following: think of your points as complex numbers. Then, the set of points (ignoring the unit square condition for the moment) where the min is smaller than some $x$ is the tubular neighborhood of radius $x$ around the union of hyperplanes $x_i=x_j,$ of which there are $n(n-1)/2.$ Now, the area of a disk of radius $c$ is proportional to $c^2,$ and the $(n-1)$-dimensional measure of the intersection of each such hyperplane with the product of unit squares, each of which is bounded above and below by some constant. So, the probability that you lie in that tubular neighborhood is proportional to $n^2c^2.$ A similar argument works in any dimension (and actually gives the distribution of the minimimum distance).

Comment: I don't understand this. If I read it right, you're saying the expected minimum distance is $\Omega(1)$ irrespective of the number of points. Of course, this violates the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: That's because there was a typo :(

Comment: so it sounds like you're agreeing with the OP, that the minimum distance between a pair of points should be $1/n$ not $1/\sqrt n$?

Comment: Yes, but in one dimension it is $1/n^2,$ I believe.

Comment: I think it's $n^{-2/d}$ (which captures both of these)

Comment: One can actually prove this  by the second moment method: Set $Z_n=\sum_{i\neq j=1}^n 1_{\|X_i-X_j\|<c/n}$. Then as in Igor's solution, $EZ_n\sim c^2$ while simple estimates show that $EZ_n^2$ is proportional to $c^2+c^4$ for $n$ large. By Cauchy-Schwartz, this shows that the probability to have $Z_n\geq 1$ remains bounded away from $0$ as $n$ increases, and taking $c$ large shows that this probability goes to $1$; a complimentary bound on $EZ_n$ with $c$ small shows that the right order is indeed $O(1/n)$.

Comment: In fact, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124579/mean-minimum-distance-for-n-random-points-on-a-unit-square-plane/124740#124740 which shows that there is nothing new under the sun...