# Minimum separation among $m$ random points on an $n$-dimensional unit sphere

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, geometry, measure-concentration, geometric-probability

Consider $m$ points $v_1, \ldots, v_m \in R^{n}$, which are uniformly distributed on the $n$-dimensional unit sphere $S^{n-1} = \{v:\|v\|_2 = 1\}$. Let the minimum separation be
$$
\rho = \min_{i,j\in{\{1,\ldots,m\}}} \|v_i - v_j\|_2. 
$$
Question: What is the expectation of $\rho$? How fast does $\rho$ converge to its expectation as $m,n\to\infty$?

Here are some closely related questions:

[Mean minimum distance for N random points on a one-dimensional line](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1294/mean-minimum-distance-for-n-random-points-on-a-one-dimensional-line)

[Mean minimum distance for N random points on a unit square (plane)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124579/mean-minimum-distance-for-n-random-points-on-a-unit-square-plane)

[Mean minimum distance for K random points on a N-dimensional (hyper-)cube](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22592/mean-minimum-distance-for-k-random-points-on-a-n-dimensional-hyper-cube)

However, the case for n-dimensional sphere seems less clear.

Comment: When you say "How fast does ρ converge to its expectation", what do you mean? I suppose you are sending $m\to\infty$, do you? Please specify!

Comment: @Wolfgang Yes I mean $m\to\infty$. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: It might also be interesting to think about limits where $m$ and $n$ diverge simultaneously.

Comment: @Carl Thanks for the suggestion. I have modified accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preprint ["Random Point Sets on the Sphere --- Hole Radii, Covering, and Separation"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07470) by Johann S. Brauchart, Edward B. Saff, Ian H. Sloan, Yu Guang Wang, and Robert S. Womersley gives the following result in Corollary 3.4:

$\mathbb{E}[N^{2/d}\Theta_\text{min}]\to C_d = (\kappa_d/2)^{-1/d}\Gamma(1+\tfrac{1}{d})$ as $N\to\infty$

It also gives a bound on the variance.

Answer (score 0):

If the angle between the vectors $v_i$ and $v_j$ is denoted by $\theta_{ij}$, then using cosine rule we have $$\rho = 2 \min_{i,j \in\{1,2,\dots,m\}}\sin({\theta_{ij}}/{2})$$ Assuming that $m$ is a large number, then minimum will occur for a very small value of $\theta_{ij}$. Hence, $$\rho \approx \min_{i,j \in\{1,2,\dots,m\}} \theta_{ij}$$ Since the points are distributed uniformly, It is not difficult to find the distribution of $\theta_{ij}$ and then find the expectation and variance of $\rho$. This I guess will give a pretty good estimate of the actual value of expectation and variance of $\rho$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If possible, could you provide more details on the estimate?