# Tightly placed sphere caps

Tags: pr.probability, geometric-probability

**Problem.** Fix a positive real $r>0$ and a positive integer $n>0$. Consider an independent, identical sample $X_1, \ldots X_n$ drawn from the uniform distribution over the unit $d$-sphere $\mathbb S^d \subset \mathbb R^{d+1}$. What is the probability that $\|X_i - X_j\| \le r$ for every $(i,j)$?

I could work out an iterated integral giving an exact formula for $d=1$, although the integral itself is quite complicated. Before proceeding further with calculations, I wanted to know if there is a prior literature on this problem. This area of mathematics seems to go by the name of geometric probability (e.g. this 1978 [textbook by Solomon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Geometric-Probability-CBMS-NSF-Conference-Mathematics/dp/0898710251)).

A similar, well-studied problem is the probability that spherical caps of radii $r$ centered at $X_1, \ldots X_n$ covers the whole sphere. A spherical cap here refers to sets of the form $\{ y \in \mathbb{S}^d | \|x-y\| \le r \}$ for each fixed $x \in \mathbb S^d$. For this problem, an exact solution is known for $d=1$ (Stevens 1939), and some work on upper and lower bounds of the probability are known for $d>1$ ([Gilbert 1965](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2333686?casa_token=No6JVeSY_HkAAAAA:XqGsE8XMjWpk15C_l2wBqoUraQB20l-MjHxGl5RF67yMd7MszXCSD6X3VF7RkFQYV3mQR3P9GbJjJhTFgJKqu4H7ewnZ71zhrSNanRPkGkg8EH6z0w)). The $d=1$ case by Stevens is as follows. The probability that $n$ randomly chosen arcs of length $a$ from a circle of *circumference* $1$ is equal to:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor 1/a \rfloor} (-1)^k \binom nk (1- ka)^{n-1} $$

Comment: I think this paper might be of help: Random Point Sets on the Sphere --- Hole Radii, Covering, and Separation (https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07470). Specifically, you're asking about the "separation" part. I think the paper mainly deals with the asymptotics for large n, but might have some info for finite n.

Comment: And arXiv's traceback helpfully reminded me I have previously linked to this paper on MO on a different question. So that question might be relevant too: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245027/minimum-separation-among-m-random-points-on-an-n-dimensional-unit-sphere/245314#245314

Comment: Thanks for the reference Yoav. I think separation in that paper is the minimum of all pairwise distances, while I am considering the maximum of all pairwise distances. Do you know if this is addressed there or elsewhere?

Comment: Sorry I misread your question the first time. So it sounds like you're asking about the diameter of a random point set? I unfortunately don't recall anything helpful to point you to for that question. A quick search on Google Scholar turned up some papers looking at the diameter of a set of uniformly random point drawn from the ball and from a compact plane set. Maybe those could be helpful. (https://doc.rero.ch/record/311708/files/10687_2007_Article_38.pdf, https://doi.org/10.1239/aap/1019160946)

Comment: @YoavKallus thanks a lot! "Diameter" is a better phrasing of the problem I posed.

Comment: Is the norm you're using to define distance the one on $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ or $\mathbb{S^d}$? The two are certainly equivalent, but I would imagine that values that look awkward in terms of one should be at least a little cleaner in the other.

Answer (score 1):

*Not an answer; too long for a comment:*

There seem to be extensive results in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.2816 Coverage processes on spheres and condition numbers for linear programming by Bürgisser et al. I am unsure whether they will help with your problem.

From the abstract:

> Let $p(n,m,\alpha)$ be the probability that $n$ spherical caps of angular radius $\alpha$ in $S^m$ do not cover the whole sphere $S^m.$ We give an exact formula for $p(n,m,α)$ in the case $\alpha \in [π/2,π]$ and an upper bound for $p(n,m,\alpha)$ in the case $\alpha \in [0,π/2]$ which tends to $p(n,m,\pi/2)$ when $\alpha \rightarrow \pi/2.$

> In the case $\alpha \in [0,\pi/2]$ this yields upper bounds for the expected number of spherical caps of radius $\alpha$ that are needed to cover $S^m.$

The authors then relate the results to the condition number of a random linear program  in $\mathbb{R}^{m+1}.$

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if this paper addresses the main question (tightly placing spherical caps) instead of the question of covering a sphere by spherical caps?