# Distance between two points on a one dimensional line

Tags: pr.probability

I have a problem similar to the one already described and solved here [Mean minimum distance for N random points on a one-dimensional line](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1294/mean-minimum-distance-for-n-random-points-on-a-one-dimensional-line):

In my case I have N random points on a line of length L populated with integers. I now select ONE random point of the N points. What is the expected distance to the nearest other point?

Cheers,

Peter

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your points are independent uniformly distributed. Then the probability that an interval of length $l$ around your point contains no other point is $(1-l/L)^{N-1}.$ I leave the rest as an exercise.